# How to create Bean with IClientConfig

Tags: spring, config, javabeans, netflix-ribbon

How do I create a `@Bean` for `IClientConfig`? I need to initialize the `ribbonLoadBalancingHttpClient` bean with a pre-configured httpclient delegate argument. The problem is that the constructor required by the `IClientConfig` bean is not loaded in the context.

This is not working to initialize the `IClientConfig`:

```
IClientConfig.Builder.newBuilder().build();
```

UPDATE
I found that every `IClientConfig` is related to a `clientName`
If I hardcoded one clientName (for e.g. "name") ribbon will always return information for clientName -> "name".

But I have more than one clientName:

```
 nameone:
    ribbon:
       listOfServers:
          localhost:1110

 nametwo:
    ribbon:
       listOfServers:
          localhost:1111

 namethree:
    ribbon:
       listOfServers:
          localhost:1112

 namefour:
    ribbon:
       listOfServers:
          localhost:1113
       IsSecure: true

 namefive:
    ribbon:
       listOfServers:
          localhost:1114

 namesix:
    ribbon:
       listOfServers:
          localhost:111
```

So I override the `@Bean` for `ribbonLoadBalancingHttpClient` but the `IClientConfig` must be also put in the context for every clientName.
How can I achieve that?

If you wonder why I want to use a custom `HttpClient`, it's to switch off self signed certification validation for ribbon client. If there's another approach, then that's also a valid answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a answer in github asked by me : https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1776